Issue passing PlatformColor to setBackgroundColorAsync in expo navigation bar react-native
I'm facing a problem when trying to use PlatformColor as an argument for the setBackgroundColorAsync function in the expo-navigation-bar package. The function expects a ColorValue, which can be either a string or an OpaqueColorValue.
However, when I pass a PlatformColor to setBackgroundColorAsync, I encounter the following error:
WARN: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Argument of an incompatible class: class java.util.HashMap cannot be passed as an argument to parameter expecting int.
This error is surprising because PlatformColor works fine with other components like the backgroundColor prop of a View, which also expects a ColorValue.
For eg, this code works perfectly:
<View style={{backgroundColor: PlatformColor('@android:color/system_neutral2_900')}}>
</View>

But not this:
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync(PlatformColor('@android:color/system_neutral2_900'));

And if i use processColor, like this:
import { processColor, PlatformColor } from 'react-native';

const color = processColor(PlatformColor('@android/system_neutral2_900'));
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync(color);

It says: Cannot convert '[object Object]' to a Kotlin type
I'm trying to dynamically set the navigation bar color to match the current theme of my Android app. Instead of using a static color like black, I want the navigation bar color to adjust to the app's overall color scheme.
PS: I have already tried using other libraries such as react-native-navigation-bar-color, but that doesn't seem to work with my app.
Is there any way to resolve this issue and pass the PlatformColor as an argument to setBackgroundColorAsync? or maybe a workaround would be helpful
